# Error message: the literal stack isn't empty for entry XXX

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am struggling with an error message that I don't understand:

> ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry ladershortgershuny while executing---line 5227 of file apacite.bst (There was 1 error message)

So far there was not a problem in my PDF file (the citation worked: it was cited in the text correctly and the article was listed in the bibliography.

But now I am trying to include new sources and because of this error, the won't work and show up like this in the PDF:
"..grew up with their fathers present (?, ?)."

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and how I could solve the problem?

This is the .bib entry for ladershortgershuny

```
@webpage{ladershortgershuny,
    Author = {Deborah Lader and Sandra Short and Jonathan Gershuny},
    Date-Added = {2015-11-28 21:16:31 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-11-28 21:19:53 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {8 October 2015},
    Month = {August},
    Url = {http://www.timeuse.org/files/cckpub/lader_short_and_gershuny_2005_kight_diary.pdf},
    Year = {2006},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.timeuse.org/files/cckpub/lader_short_and_gershuny_2005_kight_diary.pdf}}
```

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{apacite}
% lots of other packages

\begin{document}
XXX \cite{ladershortgershuny}.


XXX \footnote {XXX \citeyear{ladershortgershuny} XXX }. 


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{...,johnsonwiener,ladershortgershuny,larsen,...}

% Lots more text, figures, tables and a bibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of code? Particularly interesting is the `ladershortgershuny` entry and, maybe, the one preceding it in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Most likely, your database has a malicious entry. But we need to see a [MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to be sure.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your fast response. As I am relatively new to LaTeX, I hope that I understood your questions right. I added the .bib entry for ladershortgershuny in my main question. I made a separate .bib file for each source. Do you need something else or do you mean this by minimal example of code?

Comment: @Johannes_B see above:)

Comment: Follow the link in my comment to learn more about MWEs ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I added my MWE in the original question. Is it fine like this? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your entry has no title, and so the url triggers the error (imho a bug in apacite.bst).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I'll try to solve this:)

Answer (score 3):

This error fundamentally happens because your entry in `*.bib` contains data that are not being written to your `*.bbl` file by your `*.bst` file. The stack contents should appear in your `*.blg` file (starting on a new line after `stack=`), allowing you to see which items weren't written. It can be resolved by editing the bst file so it writes everything, or by changing the data in the bib file so that bst will write everything. It seems that this can be done by adding fields OR removing fields in the bib entry. I suspect that the rules for removing data from the stack may depend on other data; that is, the code for popping "pages" off of the stack might be locked inside an `if` statement for processing some other data that doesn't get executed if I'm missing a field that's related to pages.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem, and find if I would neglect `title`, then would be error even on `author` items.

So if you write title name, all will be fine.

But it seems a bug in setting document actually, I cannot fix it at the moment, only write title name, that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the .bib from my Mendeley account. The citation that triggers the error was a python package published on Zenodo. It was categorized as "journal article" on Mendeley at first, but once I changed the category to "computer program" and refresh the .bib in Overleaf, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Do you have an idea or assumption, why renaming helped? Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the cite.bst has a different format requirement for different citation categories. A software citation will have all info required for the "computer program" category" but lacks some information if misclassified into the "journal article" cartegory: those unknown missing information triggers the error.

Comment: This did not work for me. The only change it caused in the `.bib` file I could spot was the removal of `urldate` field. Problem still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing `@INCOLLECTION` to `@INBOOK`.
(I had to use http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/bibtex/aa.bst.)