# how do I remove the "literal not empty" error through bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bst

I am using a .bst file I modified myself that only writes a url or a doi into the .bbl file. Everything else is ignored.

It seems from here:

[Error message: the literal stack isn't empty for entry XXX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285599/error-message-the-literal-stack-isnt-empty-for-entry-xxx)

that this causes a lot of errors in the form

"---the literal stack isn't empty for entry xyz"

where xyz is a bib entry.

Is there a way to let the .bst file ignore essential fields such as title, but still overcome these errors and not have them? Where can I choose which fields are mandatory?

(Just to make it clear, I changed all bib entry calls in the .bst file to something like:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.doi
  fin.entry
}
```